# Paytm dashboard test api generate problem

Tags: api, paytm

I have been trying to integrate paytm payment in a web-project so I was trying to genrate the test api key to get the test merchant key and merchant and I did get the success message on pressing the generate key but there was no update to the page so I reloaded the page but now there is no generate button or the test api that I was expecting.

and also wanted to know is there is some other way to integrate this